# How to launch docker image with --entrypoint and arguments?

Tags: docker

I am running something like:

```
docker run --entrypoint /bin/foo full.docker.name
```

Is there any way I can pass arguments to `/bin/foo` so that when I run the above it executes:

```
/bin/foo arg1
```

I am constrained to using the `--entrypoint` flag to actually run the docker container, but am hoping there is a way to actually pass it arguments.

I am also not able to actually edit the Dockerfile being used to create the docker images..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding your arguments at the end of your docker command:

`docker run --entrypoint /bin/foo full.docker.name arg1`

Comment: Don't worry :) FYI, the --entrypoint flag is like the ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile, and the last arguments are the CMD tag.

Comment: I don't have access to the Dockerfile for this unfortunately. The part that makes me feel like a complete idiot is I was already passing arguments after full.docker.name... but apparently never thought to put this there, bah.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for: https://serverfault.com/a/647790

Use the array form of ENTRYPOiNT:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/foo", "arg1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in your dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/foo"]
```